# How do I allow for clicking on each item/post, then viewing it in a new screen?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, ionic-framework

Im trying to build a simple tutorial app list of grocery items, and then clicking on it will lead to a new page showing the grocery goods in details, such as price, quantity left etc.

Currently, clicking on the **comments** button does nothing. I see a twitch in the URL but it reverts back to its original posts url. **No syntax issues so far.**

I suspect it might by either naming convention of the states or the angular.module definitions gone wrong. Can someone enlighten me please? Thanks!

**This is the stateProvider codes**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

.state('tab', {
  url: '/tab',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'})

.state('tab.posts', {
  url: '/posts',
  views: {
    'tab-posts': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-posts.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl'}}})

.state('tab.view', {       //suspect error is here but various combos didnt work
  url: '/posts/:postId', 
  views: {
    'tab-view':{
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-showpost.html',
      controller: 'PostViewCtrl'}}})
```

**This is the postview.js file**

```
var app = angular.module('app.controllers.view', []) //error even if remove this line 
app.controller('PostViewCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, Post) {
    $scope.post = Post.find($stateParams.postId);
});
```

**This is the tab-showpost.html**

```
<a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
<a href="#/posts">Back to Posts</a>
```

**This is the tab-posts.html**

```
   <form ng-submit="submitPost()">
        <input type = "text" ng-model="post.title"/>
        <input type = "text" ng-model="post.url"/>      
        <input type = "submit" value="Add Post"/>
    </form>     
    <div ng-repeat="(postId, post) in posts">             
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
      <a href="#/posts/{{ postId }}">comments</a>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it cannot resolve your url, maybe this has to do with the way you named your routes and how they inherit eachother. Shouldnt they url be #/tab/posts/{{ postId }} ?

Else you could try and see if it works with a ^ to make the route absolute and not relative to the parent.

So to make the url work, try

```
.state('tab.view', {       //suspect error is here but various combos didnt work
  url: '^/posts/:postId', 
  views: {
    'tab-view':{
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-showpost.html',
      controller: 'PostViewCtrl'}}})
```

Else it will take on the path relative to its parent, tab in this case if i am correct and thus have the url #/tab/posts/{{ postId }}.

Comment: Thanks! The ^ doesnt work though. 

How should I change the URL?  Within the stateProvider or do you mean the html view file?

Comment: I changed <a href="#/posts/{{ postId }}">comments</a> to <a href="#/tab/posts/{{ postId }}">comments</a>....doesnt work too.

Would be be the definition of the angular.module right at the top of the js files?

Comment: That's odd, the ^ normally makes a path absolute. For example i have used this to make a path like ^/posts/:postId work as mydomain.com/#/posts/17. See if ng-href helps for setting up the href instead of the normal one. Try <a ng-href="#/posts/{{ postId }}">comments</a> or alternatively try setting up the link via some other way, but first check if the path actually works. Check if you can go to the link you want to traverse to without the href. That way you can pinpoint the problem hopefully. Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

*Not completely sure that I understand your app structure*, but here is a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/uWWiPZiNXW6o6eFsinWA?p=preview), which should follow your design

Firstly, because the **`'tab'`** state is parent for both children *`tab.posts`* and *`tab.view`*, I placed both targets inside of the **tabs.html**:

```
<div>
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <hr />
  <div ui-view="tab-posts"></div>
  <div ui-view="tab-view"></div>
</div>
```

NOTE: in fact, there could be just one even unnamed template `<div ui-view=""></div>` and both states can target that like this `views : { '' : {...`

The way, how we can go to comments from a list view is expressed this way:

```
  <a href="#/tab/{{ postId }}">comments</a>  
  <a ui-sref="tab.view({postId: postId})">comments</a>
```

The rest of your draft is mostly unchanged, just do not forget to reference all modules in the root one:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'app.controllers.view',
  'ui.router'
]);
```

The working plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uWWiPZiNXW6o6eFsinWA?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Radim, thanks for the reply! 
Sorry I didnt mention, the tab state is a footer bar that has 2 buttons and applies to all pages.

Comment: @Thinkerer but what is your issue? does my plunker help you? or would you need some other assistance? I am simply not sure what else to expplain ;)

Comment: Look, I can help you here... but you sould do something to make it easier... Check my plunker, and try to change/fork it to your needs... shwoing me what is not working. I can then go throught and try to find out what is wrong. This should work for both of us I'd say... ;) so if you want, reproduce your issue... let me know... I will try to help

Comment: Ok sure, sorry for the inconvenience, Im very new to all these. How do i co-work on the plunker code with you? Alternatively will bitbucket work for u?

Comment: The plunker has a button "For" ... click it and it will create new branch for you.. you can play with, change, extend and create the issues you have there... Then I will come and check it. Really, please, do it this way ... we'll profit from such approach even later ;) And also, others can help! that is essential

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58140/discussion-between-thinkerer-and-radim-kohler).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
<a href="#/posts/{{ postId }}">comments</a>
```

I prefer using state names in refs so that the angular will resolve the url for you. It's simpler if you do:

```
<a ui-sref="tab.view({postId:postId})">comments</a>
```